# Shaping pandas dataframe for LSTM input

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keras, lstm, index-error

I have a simple dataset consisting of only two columns (year and price of oil). Now, I need to shape them in order for keras' LSTM-layer to accept their **input_shape**.

My code looks like this, I basically need help in the **yellow marked area**. I think that I need to alter/convert X_train and X_test before (array, normalize, etc.) but I only get errors when trying...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your X_train is a Series, just use `len(X_train)` or `X_train.shape[0]`

Comment: @DaSong I tried that already. Unfortuantely, it leads to **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code would work if you keep X_train and X_test as 2 dimensional data frames. So your problem would be solve If you define

```
X_train = train[["Year"]]
X_test = test[["Year"]]
```

After that you can define you LSTM architecture as you did in the question

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I still get an error, this time: Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (122, 1)

Comment: I think you have to reshape your X_train and X_test to (Number of observations, Time Steps, Number of Variables)
So in your case you need to covert X_train and X_test to Numpy arrays and then reshape accordingly

Comment: Looking at your data it seems your code would be:

X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)

Comment: Thank's a lot, that was it!

Comment: So I guess you can accept my answer to increase my reputation :) plz

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Sorry I'm very new to Python. so what if the data was weekly what would that look like. And what if I had 3 or 4 columns instead of a series for testing data. what would the code X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1) look like?

Comment: if your X has 52 weeks per year and 3 columns  and you want to predict yearly data point of y based on 52*Number_of_years by 3 dimension X then you have to do np.array(X_train).reshape(num_observations, 52, 3)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to reshape the `X_train` like `X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, 1))` and omit the `input_shape` argument in the first LSTM layer. Input shape for LSTM layers is always (batchsize, timestep, features). See more about this [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/).

Another thing to consider is scaling the data within a "small" range such as [0, 1] so that the training process converges nice and smoothly as we do not want the weights going crazy when they get updated, but it also depends on the specific implementation/application.

You might need to work the knobs (hyperparameters such as activation functions, dropuouts, units, batch size, etc. to get better prediction performance).

Here is a full working example with comments included:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from keras.activations import relu

# data setup
years = [i for i in range(1861, 2021)]
oil = [0.49, 1.05, 3.15, 8.06, 6.59, 3.74, 2.41, 3.63, 3.64, 3.86, 4.34, 3.64, 1.83, 1.17, 1.35, 2.56, 2.42, 1.19, 0.86, 0.95, 0.86, 0.78, 1, 0.84, 0.88, 0.71, 0.67, 0.88, 0.94, 0.87, 0.67, 0.56, 0.64, 0.84, 1.36, 1.18, 0.79, 0.91, 1.29, 1.19, 0.96, 0.8, 0.94, 0.86, 0.62, 0.73, 0.72, 0.72, 0.7, 0.61, 0.61, 0.74, 0.95, 0.81, 0.64, 1.1, 1.56, 1.98, 2.01, 3.07, 1.73, 1.61, 1.34, 1.43, 1.68, 1.88, 1.3, 1.17, 1.27, 1.19, 0.65, 0.87, 0.67, 1, 0.97, 1.09, 1.18, 1.13, 1.02, 1.02, 1.14, 1.19, 1.2, 1.21, 1.05, 1.12, 1.9, 1.99, 1.78, 1.71, 1.71, 1.71, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.9, 2.08, 2.08, 1.9, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.24, 2.48, 3.29, 11.58, 11.53, 12.8, 13.92, 14.02, 31.61, 36.83, 35.93, 32.97, 29.55, 28.78, 27.56, 14.43, 18.43503937, 14.9238417, 18.22611328, 23.72582031, 20.0009144, 19.32083658, 16.97163424, 15.81762646, 17.01667969, 20.66848837, 19.09258755, 12.71566148, 17.97007782, 28.49544922, 24.44389105, 25.02325581, 28.83070313, 38.265, 54.52108949, 65.1440625, 72.38907843, 97.25597276, 61.67126482, 79.4955336, 111.2555976, 111.6697024, 108.6585178, 98.94600791, 52.38675889, 43.73416996, 54.19244048, 71.31005976, 64.21057312, 41.83834646]

data = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((years, oil)).T, columns = ["Year", "Oil Crude Price ($)"]).astype({'Year': int})

# train percentage, thus test percentage = 1 - train_split
train_split = 0.8

# scaler for inputs and outputs
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# scaling data between 0 and 1
data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data.values)

# splitting data into train set 0.6 * 160 = first 96 rows
X_train = data_scaled[:int(train_split * len(data_scaled)),0]
y_train = data_scaled[:int(train_split * len(data_scaled)),1]

# splitting data into test set 0.4 * 160 = last 64 rows
X_test = data_scaled[int(train_split * len(data_scaled)):,0]
y_test = data_scaled[int(train_split * len(data_scaled)):,1]

# sanity check, adding rows in X_train and X_test MUST add to total rows in data
assert len(X_train) + len(X_test) == len(data)

# reshaping inputs for LSTM
X_train_lstm = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, 1))
X_test_lstm = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 1, 1))

# building model with several LSTM, dropouts, and dense layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 512, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 32, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 16))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

# compiling model with rmsprop (my preferred optimizer, and loss)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

# training model for 500 epocs and 40 samples per batch
history = model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size = 20, verbose=1)

# making predictions using test set
y_pred_scaled = model.predict(X_test_lstm)

def original_scale(scaler, x, y):
    return scaler.inverse_transform(np.concatenate((x.reshape((x.shape[0], 1)), y), axis=1))

# transforming values back to original scale 
y_pred = original_scale(scaler, X_test, y_pred_scaled)[:,1] # predicted price
y_test = data.values[int(train_split * data_scaled.shape[0]):,1] #
y_test_years = data.values[int(train_split * data_scaled.shape[0]):,0]

# wrapping up putting results together in a dataframe
output = pd.DataFrame(data = np.vstack((y_test_years, y_test, y_pred)).T, columns = ["Year", "Oil Crude Price ($)", "Predicted Oil Crude Price ($)"]).astype({'Year': int})

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
    Year  Oil Crude Price ($)  Predicted Oil Crude Price ($)
0   1989            18.226113                      22.428251
1   1990            23.725820                      23.613170
2   1991            20.000914                      24.847811
3   1992            19.320837                      26.132980
4   1993            16.971634                      27.469316
5   1994            15.817626                      28.857338
6   1995            17.016680                      30.297413
7   1996            20.668488                      31.789748
8   1997            19.092588                      33.334372
9   1998            12.715661                      34.931136
10  1999            17.970078                      36.579701
11  2000            28.495449                      38.279516
12  2001            24.443891                      40.029859
13  2002            25.023256                      41.829785
14  2003            28.830703                      43.678103
15  2004            38.265000                      45.573485
16  2005            54.521089                      47.514343
17  2006            65.144063                      49.498909
18  2007            72.389078                      51.525253
19  2008            97.255973                      53.591203
20  2009            61.671265                      55.694481
21  2010            79.495534                      57.832594
22  2011           111.255598                      60.002952
23  2012           111.669702                      62.202827
24  2013           108.658518                      64.429348
25  2014            98.946008                      66.679673
26  2015            52.386759                      68.950699
27  2016            43.734170                      71.239459
28  2017            54.192440                      73.542838
29  2018            71.310060                      75.857814
30  2019            64.210573                      78.181272
31  2020            41.838346                      80.510184
```

**Package Versions:**

```
keras                     2.4.3
numpy                     1.19.2
pandas                    1.1.5
scikit-learn              0.23.2
tensorflow                2.4.1
```